# Modify all values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Code goes below:

```
d = {'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0, 'd':0}  #at the beginning, all the values are 0.
s = 'cbad'  #a string
indices = map(s.index, d.keys())  #get every key's index in s, i.e., a-2, b-1, c-0, d-3
#then set the values to keys' index
d = dict(zip(d.keys(), indices))  #this is how I do it, any better way?
print d  #{'a':2, 'c':0, 'b':1, 'd':3}
```

Any other way to do that?

PS. the code above is just a simple one to demonstrate my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this might make your code more readable:

```
dict([(x,y) for y,x in enumerate('cbad')])
```

But you should give more details what you really want to do. Your code will probably fail if the characters in `s` do not fit the keys of `d`. So `d` is just a container for the keys and the values are not important. Why not start with a list in that case?

Comment: ya, absolutely I know that. I can guarantee that the chars in s fit the keys of d. Thanks for your enumerate way, I happened to forget it.

Comment: Nice. Also you can omit the brackets.

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
d = {'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0, 'd':0}
s = 'cbad'
for k in d.iterkeys():
    d[k] = s.index(k)
```

? It's no functional programming anymore but should be more performant and more pythonic, perhaps :-).

*EDIT*: A function variant using python dict-comprehensions (needs Python 2.7+ or 3+):

```
d.update({k : s.index(k) for k in d.iterkeys()})
```

or even

```
{k : s.index(k) for k in d.iterkeys()}
```

if a new dict is okay!

Comment: For Python 3+ `iterkeys()` has been replaced with `keys()`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418481/error-dict-object-has-no-attribute-iteritems)

Answer (score 3):

use update() method of dict:

```
d.update((k,s.index(k)) for k in d.iterkeys())
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass a list of tuples to `dict`. Instead, you can use a dictionary comprehension with `enumerate`:

```
s = 'cbad'
d = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(s)}
```

If you need to process the intermediary steps, including initial setting of values, you can use:

```
d = dict.fromkeys('abcd', 0)
s = 'cbad'

indices = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(s)}

d = {k: indices[k] for k in d}         # dictionary comprehension
d = dict(zip(d, map(indices.get, d)))  # dict + zip alternative

print(d)

# {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 0, 'd': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for k in d.iterkeys():
    d[k] = s.index[k]
```

Or, if you don't already know the letters in the string:

```
d = {}
for i in range(len(s)):
    d[s[i]]=i
```

Answer (score 1):

another one liner:

```
dict([(k,s.index(k)) for (k,v) in d.items()])
```

Answer (score 0):

You choose the right way but think that no need to create dict and then modify it if you have ability to do this in the same time:

```
keys = ['a','b','c','d']
strK = 'bcad'
res = dict(zip(keys, (strK.index(i) for i in keys)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Dict comprehension for python 2.7 and above

```
{key : indice for key, indice in zip(d.keys(), map(s.index, d.keys()))}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d = {'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0, 'd':0}
>>> s = 'cbad'
>>> for x in d:  
        d[x]=s.find(x)
>>> d
    {'a': 2, 'c': 0, 'b': 1, 'd': 3}
```