# Error: " 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems' "

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to use NetworkX to read a Shapefile and use the function `write_shp()` to generate the Shapefiles that will contain the nodes and edges, but when I try to run the code it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:/Users/Felipe/PycharmProjects/untitled/asdf.py", line 4, in
<module>
    nx.write_shp(redVial, "shapefiles")   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\nx_shp.py", line
192, in write_shp
    for key, data in e[2].iteritems(): AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

I'm using Python 3.4 and installed NetworkX via pip install.

Before this error it had already given me another one that said "xrange does not exist" or something like that, so I looked it up and just changed `xrange` to `range` in the nx_shp.py file, which seemed to solve it.

From what I've read it could be related to the Python version (Python2 vs Python3).

Comment: Python 3 renamed `dict.iteritems -> dict.items`.

Comment: oh wow I feel so silly right now, thanks for the answer

Comment: @Blender: No, it didn't rename `iteritems` to `items`. The former gave you an iterator (and 3.x has no such method); the latter gives you a view (which was backported to 2.7 as `viewitems`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [iter, values, item in dictionary does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444340/iter-values-item-in-dictionary-does-not-work)

Comment: This may or may not be the equivalent page to what the OP originally linked to: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/readwrite/nx_shp.html?highlight=readwrite%20nx#module-networkx.readwrite.nx_shp

Answer (score 1185, accepted):

As you are in python3 , use `dict.items()` instead of `dict.iteritems()`

`iteritems()` was removed in python3, so you can't use this method anymore.

Take a look at Python 3.0 Wiki [Built-in Changes](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python3.0#Built-In_Changes) section, where it is stated:

> Removed `dict.iteritems()`, `dict.iterkeys()`, and `dict.itervalues()`.
>
> Instead: use `dict.items()`, `dict.keys()`, and `dict.values()`
>   respectively.

Comment: Further discussion of this is officially recorded in [PEP 469](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0469/). The recommended approach appears to be to use the `iteritems` function of the `future.utils` or `six` modules instead.

Answer (score 58):

In **Python2**, we had `.items()` and `.iteritems()` in dictionaries. `dict.items()` returned list of tuples in dictionary `[(k1,v1),(k2,v2),...]`. It copied all tuples in dictionary and created new list. If dictionary is very big, there is very big memory impact.

So they created `dict.iteritems()` in later versions of Python2. This returned iterator object. Whole dictionary was not copied so there is lesser memory consumption. People using `Python2` are taught to use `dict.iteritems()` instead of `.items()` for efficiency as explained in following code.

```
import timeit

d = {i:i*2 for i in xrange(10000000)}  
start = timeit.default_timer()
for key,value in d.items():
    tmp = key + value #do something like print
t1 = timeit.default_timer() - start

start = timeit.default_timer()
for key,value in d.iteritems():
    tmp = key + value
t2 = timeit.default_timer() - start
```

Output:

```
Time with d.items(): 9.04773592949
Time with d.iteritems(): 2.17707300186
```

In **Python3**, they wanted to make it more efficient, so moved `dictionary.iteritems()` to `dict.items()`, and removed `.iteritems()` as it was no longer needed.

You have used `dict.iteritems()` in `Python3` so it has failed. Try using `dict.items()` which has the same functionality as `dict.iteritems()` of `Python2`. This is a tiny bit migration issue from `Python2` to `Python3`.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem (using 3.5) and lost 1/2 a day to it but here is a something that works - I am retired and just learning Python so I can help my grandson (12) with it.

```
mydict2={'Atlanta':78,'Macon':85,'Savannah':72}
maxval=(max(mydict2.values()))
print(maxval)
mykey=[key for key,value in mydict2.items()if value==maxval][0]
print(mykey)
YEILDS; 
85
Macon
```

Answer (score 5):

In Python2, `dictionary.iteritems()` is more efficient than `dictionary.items()` so in Python3, the functionality of `dictionary.iteritems()` has been migrated to `dictionary.items()` and `iteritems()` is removed. So you are getting this error.

Use `dict.items()` in Python3 which is same as `dict.iteritems()` of Python2.

Answer (score 0):

for me I got the same error but for another simpler reason, this once I try to access python `dict` in javascript way using `.`: `item.data` so I got the error

```
Error: " 'item' object has no attribute 'data' "
```

so fix this I had only to use python way `item['data']`

```py
item = { id: 1, "data": "value"}
print(item.data) # Error

item = { id: 1, "data": "value"}
print(item['data']) # value
```

Answer (score -1):

The purpose of `.iteritems()` was to use less memory space by yielding one result at a time while looping. I am not sure why Python 3 version does not support `iteritems()`though it's been proved to be efficient than `.items()`

If you want to include a code that supports both the PY version 2 and 3,

```
try:
    iteritems
except NameError:
    iteritems = items
```

This can help if you deploy your project in some other system and you aren't sure about the PY version.

Answer (score -3):

As answered by RafaelC, Python 3 renamed dict.iteritems -> dict.items.
Try a different package version. This will list available packages:

```
python -m pip install yourOwnPackageHere==
```

Then rerun with the version you will try after == to install/switch version