# enumerate() for dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, enumerate

I know we use `enumerate` for iterating a list but I tried it on a dictionary and it didn't give an error.

CODE:

```
enumm = {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7}

for i, key in enumerate(enumm):
    print(i, key)
```

OUTPUT:

```
0 0

1 1

2 2

3 4

4 5

5 6

6 7
```

Can someone please explain the output?

Comment: `for i, j in enumerate(enumm)`  gets `i` incremented at every iteration, and `j` catches the usual item from the `enumerate` function argument, which in this case is a dictionary. Iterating over dicts is essentially iterating over its keys.

Answer (score 285):

On top of the already provided answers there is a very nice pattern in Python that allows you to enumerate both keys and values of a dictionary.

The normal case you **enumerate the keys** of the dictionary:

```
example_dict = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d'}

for i, k in enumerate(example_dict):
    print(i, k)
```

Which outputs:

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

But if you want to **enumerate through both keys and values** this is the way:

```
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(example_dict.items()):
    print(i, k, v)
```

Which outputs:

```
0 1 a
1 2 b
2 3 c
3 4 d
```

Comment: (+1) You could also simply use `dictionary.items()` (without enumerate) to get a view object with key-value pairs as a list of tuples.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is the highest rated answer. It's basically too much code; and potentially yields the wrong answer.  Using `enumerate` with a `dict` is potentially dangerous.  Python does not guarantee key order when using `enumerate`; it is potentially possible for keys to be emitted in a different order on subsequent runs. @roadrunner66's answer is the most correct solution.

Comment: This be ok for Python 3.7+ since dictionaries are guaranteed ordered

Answer (score 80):

The first column of output is the index of each item in `enumm` and the second one is its keys. If you want to iterate your dictionary then use .items():

```
for k, v in enumm.items():
    print(k, v)
```

And the output should look like:

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
4 4 
5 5
6 6
7 7
```

Answer (score 74):

Just thought I'd add, if you'd like to enumerate over the index, key, and values of a dictionary, your for loop should look like this:

```
for index, (key, value) in enumerate(your_dict.items()):
    print(index, key, value)
```

Comment: This question is related to issues about syntax, and this answer provided the shortest solution of two added parentheses: `idx, (k, v) in enumerate(d.items()):`

Comment: Hi Sean, I'm not sure if you're agreeing with the answer or simply saying that shorter variables names make for a better answer?

Answer (score 46):

```
dict1={'a':1, 'b':'banana'}
```

To list the dictionary in Python 2.x:

```
for k,v in dict1.iteritems():
        print k,v
```

In Python 3.x use:

```
for k,v in dict1.items():
        print(k,v)
# a 1
# b banana
```

Finally, as others have indicated, if you want a running index, you can have that too:

```
for i  in enumerate(dict1.items()):
   print(i)  

 # (0, ('a', 1))
 # (1, ('b', 'banana'))
```

But this defeats the purpose of a  [dictionary (map, associative array)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) , which is an efficient data structure for telephone-book-style look-up. Dictionary ordering could be incidental to the implementation and should not be relied upon. If you need the order, use   [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)  instead.

Comment: It's not letting me do a 2 character edit on this post, but the OP tagged this  as being for Python 3, so the print statement needs to have parenthesis around k,v.

Comment: @Mr. Me, ty, will fix.

Comment: This should be noted is only available for python2. dict.iteritems() was removed in python3, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418481/error-dict-object-has-no-attribute-iteritems-when-trying-to-use-networkx

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Ty. Updated python3 vs python2. Added comment on enumerate.

Answer (score 6):

`enumerate()` when working on list actually gives the index and the value of the items inside the list.
For example:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
for i, j in enumerate(list):
    print(i, j)
```

gives

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
7 8
8 9
```

where the first column denotes the index of the item and 2nd column denotes the items itself.

In a dictionary

```
enumm = {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7}
for i, j in enumerate(enumm):
    print(i, j)
```

it gives the output

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
```

where the first column gives the index of the `key:value` pairs and the second column denotes the `keys` of the dictionary `enumm`.

So if you want the first column to be the `keys` and second columns as `values`, better try out `dict.iteritems()`[(Python 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10458567/8881141) or `dict.items()` (Python 3)

```
for i, j in enumm.items():
    print(i, j)
```

output

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
```

Voila

Comment: This is not true for dictionaries. Your code will iterate over the dictionary using an index (for the iteration) but not giving the key-value combinations of the dictionary. Use dict.items() instead.

Comment: yes you can also go ahead with dict.items(). Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are using `enumerate` hence your `i` is actually the index of the key rather than the key itself.

So, you are getting `3` in the first column of the row `3 4`even though there is no key `3`.

`enumerate` iterates through a data structure(be it list or a dictionary) while also providing the current iteration number.

Hence, the columns here are the iteration number followed by the key in dictionary `enum`

Others Solutions have already shown how to iterate over key and value pair so I won't repeat the same in mine.

Answer (score 4):

1. Iterating over a Python dict means to iterate over its keys exactly the same way as with `dict.keys()`
2. The order of the keys is determined by the implementation code and you cannot expect some specific order:

   > Keys and values are iterated over in an arbitrary order which is
   >   non-random, varies across Python implementations, and depends on the
   >   dictionary’s history of insertions and deletions. If keys, values and
   >   items views are iterated over with no intervening modifications to the
   >   dictionary, the order of items will directly correspond.

That's why you see the indices 0 to 7 in the first column. They are produced by `enumerate` and are always in the correct order. Further you see the dict's keys 0 to 7 in the second column. They are not sorted.

Answer (score 3):

That sure must seem confusing. So this is what is going on. The first value of enumerate (in this case i) returns the next index value starting at 0 so 0, 1, 2, 3, ... It will always return these numbers regardless of what is in the dictionary. The second value of enumerate (in this case j) is returning the values in your dictionary/enumm (we call it a dictionary in Python). What you really want to do is what roadrunner66 responded with.

Answer (score 3):

Python3:

One solution:

```
enumm = {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7}
for i, k in enumerate(enumm):
    print("{}) d.key={}, d.value={}".format(i, k, enumm[k]))
```

---

```
Output:
0) enumm.key=0, enumm.value=1
1) enumm.key=1, enumm.value=2
2) enumm.key=2, enumm.value=3
3) enumm.key=4, enumm.value=4
4) enumm.key=5, enumm.value=5
5) enumm.key=6, enumm.value=6
6) enumm.key=7, enumm.value=7
```

An another example:

```
d = {1 : {'a': 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3},
     2 : {'a': 10, 'b' : 20, 'c' : 30}
    }    
for i, k in enumerate(d):
        print("{}) key={}, value={}".format(i, k, d[k])
```

---

```
Output:    
    0) key=1, value={'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
    1) key=2, value={'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may find it useful to include index inside key:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
d = {(i, k): v for i, (k, v) in enumerate(d.items())}
```

Output:

```
{(0, 'a'): True, (1, 'b'): False}
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
d = {0: 'zero', '0': 'ZERO', 1: 'one', '1': 'ONE'}

print("List of enumerated d= ", list(enumerate(d.items())))
```

output:

```
List of enumerated d=  [(0, (0, 'zero')), (1, ('0', 'ZERO')), (2, (1, 'one')), (3, ('1', 'ONE'))]
```