# How to iterate over dictionary items and indexes starting from 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, iteration

---

[image: This is the image]

I want to make it like this: (sorted number '1-3' instead of '0-2')

1. name John
2. age 20
3. gender Male

Comment: hi, please send us code that i snippet code . to quick answer

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data. See [mre].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244380/enumerate-for-dictionary-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(my_lib.items()):
    print(i+1, x, y)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) with its `start` argument, it's literally made for this:

```
for i, (key, value) in enumerate(my_lib.items(), start=1):
    print(i, key, value)
```