# why my menu of dictionary does not appearing?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, object

I am trying to display a menu for a group of routers that is described by a dictionary that contains pieces of information about their status. To do this, I have a function that takes the dictionary `routers` that contain the device information as input. The dictionary is converted into a list of dictionary objects, called `router_list`, sorted by the value of device name, with the use of a for-loop. All the devices are saved into the `menu_text` variable, which in turn is used to enumerate and print the devices.

When I run this code I get this error:

```
 python3 menu.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "menu.py", line 28, in <module>
    'password': '2020'
  File "menu.py", line 6, in show_menu
    router_list.append("%s. %s " % ((i+2), value['name'],))
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Here's my code:

```
def show_menu(routers):
    router_list = []
    i = 0
    for key, value in enumerate(routers):           
        router_list.append("%s. %s " % ((i+2), value['name'],))
        i = i + 1

    menu_text = '\n'.join(router_list)

    print(("""
---------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------

0.EXIT
1.CONFIG ALL
"""+ menu_text +"""
---------------------------------------------------------
          """))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    show_menu({
    'name': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': '192.168.122.217',
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': '2020'
     })
```

Comment: How many routers info do you intend to use? The menu would show only the `name` of the router, right?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=TypeError%3A+string+indices+must+be+integers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I seeing "TypeError: string indices must be integers"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077675/why-am-i-seeing-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers)

Comment: its depend on the environment sir, actually, i want  to used with another function to sand some configuration on the topology by selecting a number from the list menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a list of dictionaries to `show_menu()`, for example

```py
routers = [
    {
        'name': 'cisco_ios',
        'ip': '192.168.122.217',
        'username': 'admin',
        'password': '2020'
     },
]
show_menu(routers)
```

The reason is that, in your `show_menu()` code, you assume that `value` is a dictionary, so the argument for `routers` should be a list of dictionaries.

Comment: yeah, this is true think you, but actually i want to used with another function to sand some configuration on the topology by selecting a number from the list-menu to refer which device

Comment: sorry for late response.  I am not very clear about your need, but if you want to use a number to select a router, then the list of router dictionaries should work, as the list index could be the same as the router number.

Answer (score 1):

While looping over a dictionary using `enumerate()`, you get index and key, not key and value. And, `value['name']` would result in an error as `value` doesn't represent the dictionary, it is the key (`name`, `ip`, etc. in your case).

For looping over the key/value pair, you can use `dict.items()` like this:

```
for k, v in dict.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Relevant thread: [enumerate() for dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244380/enumerate-for-dictionary-in-python)

---

As you're passing only one router information as dictionary i.e. `routers`, you don't need to loop over it to extract the name of the router.

You can simply use `routers['name']` and you're done!

Example ([live](https://ideone.com/FTbVOG)):

```
def show_menu(routers):
    print(("""
---------------------------------------------------------
0.EXIT
1.CONFIG ALL
2."""+ routers['name'] +"""
---------------------------------------------------------
          """))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    show_menu({
    'name': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': '192.168.122.217',
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': '2020'
     })
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
0.EXIT
1.CONFIG ALL
2.cisco_ios
---------------------------------------------------------
```

But, if there are multiple routers then you can use a list of dictionaries denoting routers and loop over it using `for` like this ([live](https://ideone.com/SEv6e8)):

```
def show_menu(routers):
    router_list = []
    i = 0
    for router in routers:
        router_list.append("%s. %s " % ((i+2), router['name'],))
        i = i + 1

    menu_text = '\n'.join(router_list)

    print(("""
---------------------------------------------------------
0.EXIT
1.CONFIG ALL
"""+ menu_text +"""
---------------------------------------------------------
          """))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    show_menu([{
        'name': 'cisco_ios',
        'ip': '192.168.122.217',
        'username': 'admin',
        'password': '2020'
     },
     {
        'name': 'cisco_ios_123',
        'ip': '192.168.xxx.xxx',
        'username': 'admin',
        'password': '2021'
     }
     ])
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
0.EXIT
1.CONFIG ALL
2. cisco_ios 
3. cisco_ios_123 
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: this is true but i have to enumerate those dicts for the selecting

Comment: @AbdelhakBoumezrag: Why is that? How do you get that dictionary of router info? If there are multiple routers then what would you get? A single dictionary with all of the routers? Is that right?