# Dictionary indexing in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, parsing

I have a dictionary in the following format:
Key (string) : Value (list[string])

```
my_dict = {'Foo': ['Lorem', 'Ipsum', 'Dolor', 'Baz'], 'Bar': ['Amet', 'Consectetur'], 'Baz': ['...'], 'Lorem': ['...'], & so on...}
```

I want to access this dictionary by indexing each key, such that Foo = 1, Bar = 2, Baz = 3, Lorem = 4, Ipsum = 5.. and so on

I want to choose a key by index, then pick a value, and go to that index, and so on.

For example: If I pick 1, I will go to Foo. Then from Foo, I will go to either Lorem, Ipsum, Dolor, or Baz.

I am essentially creating another dictionary dict2, which will hold a number of integers as the new key, and the key from dict1 as its value.

First I tried to call dict2.update({int_list:dict1.keys()) but this resulted in an unhashable type error. Ok, so I converted the list into a tuple and it updated but did not result in the dictionary I wanted.

What is an appropriate way to go about doing this?

Comment: This reads like you want a graph.

Comment: Does the "dict indexing" code need to keep up to date with changes to underlying `my_dict`, or is `my_dict` unchanging?

Comment: Read through: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244380/enumerate-for-dictionary-in-python

Comment: Related: [Accessing dictionary items by position in Python 3.6+ efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52507860/674039)

Comment: @wim Either, I think. I will have (n) random look up functions called on the dict. If two 'lookups' are ever at the same key, then this key is eliminated as a possible route from the dict and lookup is abandoned. I hope this makes sense!

Comment: @PeterParker What I'm asking is whether `my_dict` will have items added or removed (in which case the lookup needs to keep in sync), or it is unmodified (in which case the lookup can be created once)

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate()` to pair each index with a key, then convert that to a dictionary:

```
dict2 = dict(enumerate(my_dict, 1))
```

Comment: This will be very inefficient if dict2 needs to be kept in sync with my_dict, though.

Comment: That's a fault of his general idea of having the second index. I'm not sure why he needs that.

Answer (score 0):

First, you might need to get the dic.items() and loop through, you will need list to append the values of the other list, this is the code, below:

my_dict = {'Foo': ['Lorem', 'Ipsum', 'Dolor', 'Baz'],
'Bar': ['Amet', 'Consectetur']}

```
  key_list = list()
  dic = dict()
  total = list()
  for key, groups in my_dict.items():
    joined_list = my_dict['Foo'] + my_dict['Bar']
    print(f'{key}: {groups}')
    key_list.append(key)
    dic[key] = key.count(key)
    s = key_list.index(key) + 1
    dic[key] = s
    for index, value in enumerate(joined_list):
        # print(index, value)
        total.append(index)
        dic[value] = index + 1 + s
  print(dic)
```

Comment: please  @PeterParker note that for the keys which was represented by the actual key(my_dict['Foo'] & my_dict['Bar']);  you can use dict.keys() to get each key in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Define a global index variable and use the the walrus operator, [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html), to increment it in a dictionary comprehension. If the keys should start from 1 set the global index to 0.

```
my_dict = {'Foo': ['Lorem', 'Ipsum', 'Dolor', 'Baz'], 'Bar': ['Amet', 'Consectetur'], 'Baz': ['...'], 'Lorem': ['...']}

i = 0   # global index
d = {(i:=i+1): v for v in my_dict.values()}
```