# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Tags: python, json, iteritems

Question:I am getting an error while running the below code . I am new to this and not sure how to fix the issue. creae function to assign each coordinates point to its borough.

```
    def find_borough(lat,lon):
        """
        return the borough of a location given its latitude and longitude
        lat: float, latitude
        lon: float, longitude
        """
        boro = 0 # initialize borough as 0
        for k,v in boros.iteritems(): # update boro to the right key corresponding to the parent polygon
            if v['polygon'].contains(Point(lon,lat)):
                boro = k
                break # break the loop once the borough is found
        return [boro]

## Analyse the cluster now
# create data frame of boroughs
    df = data1[data1.Trip_duration>=1350]
    orig_dest = []
    for v in df[['Pickup_latitude','Pickup_longitude','Dropoff_latitude','Dropoff_longitude']].values:
        orig_dest.append((find_borough(v[0],v[1])[0],find_borough(v[2],v[3])[0]))
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(orig_dest)



        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
        <ipython-input-92-6a4861346be4> in <module>()
             35 orig_dest = []
             36 for v in df[['Pickup_latitude','Pickup_longitude','Dropoff_latitude','Dropoff_longitude']].values:
        ---> 37     orig_dest.append((find_borough(v[0],v[1])[0],find_borough(v[2],v[3])[0]))
             38 df2 = pd.DataFrame(orig_dest)
             39 

        <ipython-input-92-6a4861346be4> in find_borough(lat, lon)
             24     """
             25     boro = 0 # initialize borough as 0
        ---> 26     for k,v in boros.iteritems(): # update boro to the right key corresponding to the parent polygon
             27         if v['polygon'].contains(Point(lon,lat)):
             28             boro = k

        AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Comment: You're trying to use a Python 2 method on Python 3.

Comment: use `boros.items()` instead

Comment: Thank you Sriram. It worked!

Comment: Asked before:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418481/error-dict-object-has-no-attribute-iteritems-when-trying-to-use-networkx

Answer (score 17):

In Python 3, `dict.iteritems` was renamed to `dict.items`. You should do this renaming in your code as well. In Python 2, `dict.items` works too, though this will give back a list of items, whereas `dict.iteritems` in Python 2 (and `dict.items` in Python 3) gives back a generator, enabling low-memory looping over the items.