# Python create a list of all functions starting with specific name

Tags: python

**Scenario**:

I am working with python to execute some functions in cycle... over and over again.

**How I do it**:

I create a list with all the functions I want to execute, and then I do so.

```
# Define the functions before using 'em
def this_f:
    pass

def the_other:
    pass

....

# List of f() I want to run
funciones_escrapeadoras = [
    this_f,
    the_other,
    ...
    ]

# Call them all, cyclically
while True:
    for funcion_escrapeadora in funciones_escrapeadoras:
        funcion_escrapeadora()
```

**Question**:

If I prefixed all the functions I want to be part of the list, is there a way to automatically identify them and put them into that list?

**Example**:

I define the functions:

autorun_lalaa, hello_world, autorun_lololo, ...

And only autorun_lalaa and autorun_lololo and autorun_* will be part of the list.

**Purpose**:

To add in the functions I want to run, without needing to update the list.

Comment: do you have a list of functions prefixed with `autorun` ?

Comment: No, that is the list I want python itself to generate, by somehow (<-- here lies my question's core) making python to iterate over all the functions defined in the current .py file and filtering those starting with autorun (or whatever other prefix)

Comment: i would suggest make a global list which will be updated by every function with the name of itself

Comment: @ArpitSolanki great idea, but I will stick to John's answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the builtin [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) or `globals()`:

```
for name, obj in locals().iteritems():
    if name.startswith('autorun_'):
        obj()
```

You could also make a Decorator which is described here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators - then the functions don't need a name prefix, you could instead have the decorator add the function to a list.

Comment: Perfect, sir. Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually the decorator solution is by far the best one - it's highly explicit and as safe and robust as it can be.

Comment: Please, consider this, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418481/error-dict-object-has-no-attribute-iteritems-when-trying-to-use-networkx

Answer (score 1):

To list the names of all the functions and variables of a module you can use:

```
funcs_n_vars = dir(modulename)
```

Then you can iterate over it to filter the list:

```
filtered_funcs = [func for func in funcs_n_vars if ('filter' in func)]
```

Finally, to call the methods from the list, you can do:

```
for func in filtered_funcs
    method_to_call = getattr(modulename, func)
    result = method_to_call()
```

Comment: Thank you too, but I will go with John's answer. I don't need the functions from a module but from current file, and locals() is the approach I was looking for.