# How to rank the number of times a word is used in a list

Tags: python

I have a list that contains multiple words. It looks like this:

```
Food = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'orange', 'strawberry', 'apple', 'orange', banana', apple']
```

Is there any way that I could rank the number of times each fruit is used? The code also has to allow for multiple places to make is look like this:

```
(apple, 1), (orange, 1), (banana, 3), (strawberry, 4).
```

I tried to use the ranking function but had no idea what to do after I downloaded from github and unzipped it.

I am not looking for a count of how many times each word is used but more like a ranking kind of thing. Something like 1st, 2nd, 3rd. But let's say that if two of the items have 3 occurrences while the rest have less it will look like: 1, 1, 3, 4, 5 etc.

Comment: Are the items in the list `Food` variables? If they are string they are expected to be within quotes.

Comment: Oh, yes. My bad, I forgot.

Comment: I am not looking for a count of how many times each word is used but more like a ranking kind of thing. Something like 1st, 2nd, 3rd. But let's say that if two of the items have 3 occurrences while the rest have less it will look like: 1, 1, 3, 4, 5 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Counter` which is a subclass of a `dict`

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: food = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'orange', 'strawberry', 'apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'apple']

In [3]: c = Counter(food)

In [4]: c
Out[4]: Counter({'apple': 3, 'banana': 2, 'orange': 3, 'strawberry': 1})

In [5]: c['orange']
Out[5]: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

Built up a dictionary of the counters, and then sort the dict by the values.

```
Food = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'orange', 'strawberry', 'apple', 'orange', 'banana','apple']

d = {}
for fruit in Food:
    d[fruit] = d.get(fruit, 0) + 1

ranked = sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

where ranked is:

```
[('orange', 3), ('apple', 3), ('banana', 2), ('strawberry', 1)]
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can reverse that order so that the apple and orange come first?

Comment: yep, just edited it to do that!

Comment: `ranked = sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418481/error-dict-object-has-no-attribute-iteritems?rq=1

Comment: Thank you LeKhan9, that fixed it. I also have one last question. Is there any way that I can print the "first places"? There will be two.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add the foods to a dictionary where the value is the count. For example, here is a piece of code that goes through every food in the list and updates the count. Then, you can optionally convert it back to a list:

```
Food = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "orange", "strawberry", "apple", "orange", "banana", "apple"]

FoodDict = {}
for f in Food:
    if f in FoodDict:
        FoodDict[f] += 1
    else:
        FoodDict[f] = 0
print(FoodDict)
FoodCountList = [(f, FoodDict[f]) for f in FoodDict]
print(FoodCountList)
```

Which prints:

```
{'apple': 2, 'orange': 2, 'banana': 1, 'strawberry': 0}
[('apple', 2), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 1), ('strawberry', 0)]
```